# How to make background image responsive and cover all area

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

hello i want to add background on my site but everytimes i do it wont fit in my website
i tried

```
background-size:auto;
```

i also tried cover it even make image worse

```
background-size:cover;
```

i tried `background-size:contain;` too ,good then cover but not worth it there is still lots of space

am i the only one finding this tought or does any other have same problem ?

i also tried`<body background="img_url" >` it doesn't help

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: `cover` and `contain` are generally the best options for a responsive background image. The biggest issue that you have with responsive background images is you’re trying to make one image work for an infinite number of screen dimensions. Your best solution is probably using media queries to set the background image and the size to each breakpoint where you’re finding an issue.

Comment: I think you can check out this article by css-trick
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

If you set the of the image to 100% and height to auto (I believe) it will keep the proportions of the image and cover 100% of the width of the parent element.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about using background-image not using <img /> tag